# How to set hierarchical structure values through the Web API using friendly names and without exposing the structure itself to the user?

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures, asp.net-web-api

We're developing some sort of Web API, which allows us to set values for hierarchical structure like this:

```
<ROOT>
    <COLLECTION_ELEMENT>

        <SIMPLE_ELEMENT /> // alias = nail
        <SIMPLE_ELEMENT /> // alias = hammer

        <COLLECTION_ELEMENT>
            <SIMPLE_ELEMENT /> // red
            <SIMPLE_ELEMENT /> // green
        </COLLECTION_ELEMENT>

    </COLLECTION_ELEMENT>
        ....
    <COLLECTION_ELEMENT>

        <SIMPLE_ELEMENT /> // alias = nail
        <SIMPLE_ELEMENT /> // alias = hammer

        <COLLECTION_ELEMENT>
            <SIMPLE_ELEMENT /> // red
            <SIMPLE_ELEMENT /> // green
        </COLLECTION_ELEMENT>

    </COLLECTION_ELEMENT>
</ROOT>
```

As you can see we have two types of elements `COLLECTION_ELEMENT`, which can contain `SIMPLE_ELEMENT` and other `COLLECTION_ELEMENT`s. Each field in hierarchical structure has an alias, which is actually exposed to the partner (we do not want to expose the structure of our hierarchy), alias is unique per structure.

The problem is that we do not really know how to give our partner good API when he want to update/set `SIMPLE_ELEMENT`, which belongs to the nested `COLLECTION_ELEMENT`. For example,

Right now I have two `COLLECTION_ELEMENT`s on the root level. I want to update `hammer` value for second `COLLECTION_ELEMENT` entry. So for right now we're using such structure `hammer[1][2] - newHammerValue`.

`1` Shows that it should set first occurrence of `hammer` inside 2 parent collection elements. That works pretty well, but if we have more complex structure with a lot of nested levels we can have something like this `hammer[1][2][3][5][2]`, in that case it's pretty hard to handle all the errors and index mismatches and it doesn't give our partner any idea what he is setting right now.

So the questions is, how to set hierarchical structure values through the `WebApi` using friendly names and without exposing the structure itself to the user? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you collection elements had aliases then you would be able to use a natural URI path structure, which is intended to map hierarchies.

```
<ROOT>
    <COLLECTION_ELEMENT>  //alias = foo

        <SIMPLE_ELEMENT /> // alias = nail
        <SIMPLE_ELEMENT /> // alias = hammer

        <COLLECTION_ELEMENT> /alias = bar
            <SIMPLE_ELEMENT /> // red
            <SIMPLE_ELEMENT /> // green
        </COLLECTION_ELEMENT>

    </COLLECTION_ELEMENT>
        ....
    <COLLECTION_ELEMENT> //baz

        <SIMPLE_ELEMENT /> // alias = nail
        <SIMPLE_ELEMENT /> // alias = hammer

        <COLLECTION_ELEMENT>  //blunk
            <SIMPLE_ELEMENT /> // red
            <SIMPLE_ELEMENT /> // green
        </COLLECTION_ELEMENT>

    </COLLECTION_ELEMENT>
</ROOT>
```

With this hierarchy, your example becomes

```
 /baz/hammer
```

Is there a piece of the puzzle I am missing?

Comment: well, but in this case we will expose the structure of our hierarchy to the partner, we want to avoid this in fact. also if maxOccurance of baz is more than 1, so I can have two 'baz' and if I want to set the value of the second one I have to specify an index. something like this /baz[2]/hammer?

Comment: @JevgenijNekrasov Ok, which is just an XPath like syntax.  I'm not sure how you can provide structural access to a hierarchy without exposing the hierarchy structure.